# How to log mysql slow queries for specific database

Tags: mysql, performance, configuration, centos

My sql instance has a few different databases.

I have configured my.cnf to log slow queries with the following lines:

```
log_error=/var/log/mysql/error.log
log_queries_not_using_indexes=1
slow_query_log=1
slow_query_log_file=/var/log/mysql/mysql-slow.log
long_query_time=1
```

It works fine, but I'd like to have logs only for the specific database.

Is it possible ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use mysql slow log in file then use this command for find slow log row of  specific database:

```
cat  /var/lib/mysql/slow.log |grep -A 3 {your_db_name}
```

Answer (score 2):

The slow queries log is a global parameter.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_slow_query_log

Comment: `long_query_time` too unfortunately. Even though you can SET it without GLOBAL. (Or maybe I'm missing something.)

Comment: Is it possible to log slow queries for the specific database in some other way ?